# An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hi guys i started learning ASP.net but when i am starting `Internet Information Service` from Control Panel->Programs->Turn Windows features on ,it is displaying following error:

```
An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed.
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: That's not how you "start IIS". That's how you install/uninstall it.